# Python import all module object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following files:

```
./main.py
./lib/__init__.py
./lib/lib.py
```

,

```
$ cat lib/lib.py

def method():
    return 'method'
```

,

```
$ cat lib/__init__.py

from .lib import *
```

,

```
$ cat main.py

import lib

def main():
    print(lib.lib)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I don't know why `lib.lib` is defined, it's not a variable in the lib.py file.
Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reference the lib.py file when you should be trying to use the functionality from the lib file. i.e. `lib.somelibfunction()`...

Comment: You have two `cat main.py` lines; I *think* the first one should really be `cat lib/lib.py` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lib.lib` object is the nested `lip.py` file inside the `lib` package.

Once you have imported the sub module, it also becomes available as an attribute of the package (unless you *also* included a `lib` name in the `__init__.py` file.

The Python 3.3 module loader (which is implemented in Python) simply sets a [nested module as an attribute on the parent](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/910ec3471d55/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#l1537):

> ```
> # [find a loader and load the module object, setting sys.modules[name]]
> module = sys.modules[name]
> if parent:
>     # Set the module as an attribute on its parent.
>     parent_module = sys.modules[parent]
>     setattr(parent_module, name.rpartition('.')[2], module)
> ```

This behaviour is more or less implied in the [Python packages documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages):

> All modules have a name. Subpackage names are separated from their parent package name by dots, akin to Python’s standard attribute access syntax. Thus you might have a module called `sys` and a package called `email`, which in turn has a subpackage called `email.mime` and a module within that subpackage called `email.mime.text`.

Comment: Thanks, can you point out to me where in the docs this behavior is specified?

Comment: @simonzack read up on [relative imports](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), also [packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: @simonzack: I *suspect* it may be documented in http://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages.html but I am still scanning that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this part, perhaps? "Whenever a submodule of a package is loaded, Python makes sure that the package itself is loaded first, loading its `__init__.py` file if necessary. The same for packages. Thus, when the statement `import Sound.Effects.echo` is executed, it first ensures that `Sound` is loaded; then it ensures that `Sound.Effects` is loaded; and only then does it ensure that `Sound.Effects.echo` is loaded (loading it if it hasn't been loaded before)." Not sure if that differs in Python 3, though.

Comment: @JAB: No. The part where `lib.__dict__['lib']` is being set to support the expectation that `lib.lib` should work even when not explicitly imported under that name in `lib/__init__.py`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is interesting. All the submodules in a package directory are referenceable without explicit importing, yet subpackages are not...

Comment: @JAB: All modules require explicit importing before they are accessible through this method, but packages may elect to import submodules on import.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, oops, seems I forgot to remove an import line in the `__init__.py` of the package I was testing with. You're right. It seems that is somewhat of a result of what I stated, however; with `from` statements, all subpackages/submodules in the chain from the top level to the referenced element will be imported, but those modules will only become referenceable when a parent package is imported (however, once that parent package is imported, _all_ subpackages/submodules in the chain from the imported package to the referenced element will be available for use).

Comment: And, of course, importing a submodule or subpackage will cause all subpackages above it in the package's hierarchy to be imported and referenceable. It's quite fascinating.